# Error when open new DNNModule template project in visual studio

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, dotnetnuke-7

I want create a module with DNNModule template but when create module template get this error.

> The Web Application Project DNNModule7 is configured to use IIS.  The
>   Web server 'http://dnndev.me/desktopmodules/DNNModule7' could not be
>   found

[image]

I search in internet and found a solution I run as administrator visual studio but  in this way the DNNModule template option  hide .
[image]
Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to kicked off this error message:

1. Open IIS.
2. Create new website dnndev.me on IIS Server.
3. Folder of this website must be the path of your actual DNN website from where you are creating DNN modules.
4. Try to create modules using Chritoc's DNN template.

For more information about this error, check this [URL](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/the-web-application-project-is-configured-to-use-iis-the-webserver-could-not-be-found).

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have a website with this properties , but I did this work but don't solved.

Comment: I use this way : (  Open IIS Manager >> Select DNNDEV.ME website (which you previously created) >> Click Bindings >> add dnndev.me to your bindings with port 80.  )  and Now worked currently

Comment: @programmer138200 Great, Happy to help!